# Restart MC server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, minecraft

Is there anyway I am able to restart a minecraft server with nodejs?

I want to be able to do /restart in discord using discordjs and nodejs and that being able to restart or start a minecraft server on the same vps.

Comment: 1+ for telling me that there are bots for discord

Answer (score 1):

I've created an script which allows you to to that.

***READ THE COMMENT AND CHANGE THE PATHS AND HAVE A LOOK AT THE START.BAT***

It should work for linux too, just change start.bat to start.sh

https://gist.github.com/simonmeusel/1de7166288b12c04518c59158a85f5ef